# JSTL replace character in variable with HTML tag

Tags: java, jstl

I've got a variable in JSTL and would like to replace all commas with

```
<c:set var="colTxt" value="${fn:replace(colTxt,',','<br />')}" />
```

This however shows the error:

> The value of attribute 'value' associated with an element type "c:set" must not contain the '<' character

What can I do about this?

Comment: Your example does not produce an error under Tomcat 6.0.32 (web.xml specifying servlet spec 2.5). Can you provide specifics on the container that is yielding the error?

Comment: @jt. you will get this error only when you use a XML based view technology such as JSPX or Facelets. You should then escape XML-special characters which are used been "plain vanilla". There are only five of such characters, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

When printing it using `<c:out>`, then ensure that you add `escapeXml="false"`, otherwise you'll see `<br />` literally showing as-is instead of being parsed as a real HTML linebreak.

However, when `${colTxt}` contains user-controlled input, then disabling XML escaping might potentially create a XSS hole. You might want to solve the problem differently, e.g.

```xml
<c:forEach items="${fn:split(colTxt, ',')}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item}" /><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Ah, finally. I had to set escapeXml to false on the c:out.
I consider this a little bit dirty. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This is a lifesaver!